# How can I add date to a filename using sed

Tags: unix, sed, rename

I need a `sed` line that will rename `stroodle-EMAIL-MSG.mail` to `stro{dd_mm_yyyy}.zip`

will sed be able to do this?

Comment: did you want the todays date on the renamed file?

Comment: `s/odle-EMAIL-MSG\.mail/\{dd_mm_yyyy\}.zip/`

Comment: Have you tried doing it anyway?

Comment: i tried to use cut -c1-4 so i get the first 4 chars the ${DATE} to add to the end but this was not right.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, thats close but i need to take the first 4 chars as there will be different filenames going forward instead of removing everything after the first 4.

Comment: why do you want to use sed for renaming files, while tagging question with bash?  Isn't bash good enough for renaming?

Answer (score 0):

As you were told in comments of your post, you'd probably better not use `sed` for this task.

Instead, consider using UNIX `date` command. Assuming you want current date, and using `bash` syntax:

```
mv "stroodle-EMAIL-MSG.mail" \
   "stroodle{$(date +%d_%m_%Y)}.zip"
```

File will be renamed `stroodle{09_07_2014}.zip`.

If you want to use another date instead, e.g. last Christmas day:

```
mv "stroodle-EMAIL-MSG.mail" \
   "stroodle{$(date +%d_%m_%Y -d 'December 25 2013')}.zip"
```

This time your file will be renamed `stroodle{25_12_2013}.zip`.
(See `man date` or, even better, `info date` for details on available string formats for `-d` option for `date`).

Now if you really have to use `sed` (maybe you want to change this name inside a text file?), you could use something like:

```
sed "s/stroodle-EMAIL-MSG.mail/stro{$(date +%d_%m_%Y)}.zip/" input_file
```

Remark: to better sort your files by date, you might consider to use ISO 8601 format with `date +%F` instead of `date +%d_%m_%Y`. I like [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/).